# Wait for job/pod completion in Kubernetes or Google Container Engine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What's the best way in script to wait for a job or pod to complete in Kubernetes or Google Container Engine?

In particular, it would be better to be notified rather than polling for status in `kubectl`, but I'd be happy with a fairly efficient loop without any slips between the cracks. Essentially, I'd like the equivalent of a plain `docker run` since that blocks until command termination, but I don't want to use docker directly in this case.

I looked at [Github Issue #1899](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1899) but it looks unresolved as yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tell when Job is Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686568/tell-when-job-is-complete)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really what it was designed for, but you could run `kubectl attach $POD`. It'll show you the output of the pod while it's running and automatically terminate once the pod is done running.

Of course, you'll have to handle the error that it prints if the pod is already done running, since it's only really meant for use on pods that are currently running.

Comment: So I guess what people do is polling to check for completion?

Comment: I'd also like to know how to handle the case where the pod hasn't started yet, so we need to poll for started-ness before running the `attach` command.