# Tell when Job is Complete

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

I'm looking for a way to tell (from within a script) when a Kubernetes Job has completed. I want to then get the logs out of the containers and perform cleanup.

What would be a good way to do this? Would the best way be to run `kubectl describe job <job_name>` and grep for `1 Succeeded` or something of the sort?

Comment: To wait for pod to be running, use "condition=ready". Alternatively, you can wait for deployment rollout status. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60810347/658497

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073453/wait-for-kubernetes-job-to-complete-on-either-failure-success-using-command-line

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Since version 1.11, you can do:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob
```

and you can also set a timeout:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=30s job/myjob
```

Comment: Is it possible to have an indefinite timeout (wait forever)?

Comment: @JoãoMatos The default `--timeout` is 30 seconds. Specifying negative values for `--timeout` means "wait for a week" (which is, in practice, almost indefinite). Take a look at the [kubectl wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) reference.

Comment: I search for something I can easily implement in my YAML config files and a small docker image from [groundnuty/k8s-wait-for](https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for) met my expectations.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just following the log of the job? If there's only one pod, doing `kubectl logs job/myjob --follow` will effectively wait for the job to finish, regardless of its success (`condition=complete` does trigger when the job fails)

Comment: If the pods for the job fail, this command would timeout since there is no event for the job.

Comment: @Coo That command will fail until the job has had a chance to start up, so there's a race condition there.

Comment: Actually the race condition is present with the `wait` command in the answer as well.

Answer (score 32):

You can visually watch a job's status with this command:

```
kubectl get jobs myjob -w
```

The `-w` option watches for changes. You are looking for the `SUCCESSFUL` column to show `1`.

For waiting in a shell script, I'd use this command:

```
until kubectl get jobs myjob -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[? 
    (@.type=="Complete")].status}' | grep True ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

Comment: what do you think about waiting on `status.succeeded = 1` ?

Comment: @GuidoGarcía If you use status.succeeded = 1 then you've got the problem when a Job has multiple completions status.succeeded is set to 1 when the first one is finished, not all of them like with conditions.type = Complete

Comment: The shell script answer this will wait forever on a "failed" job, as a failed job will return nothing

Comment: Isn't there a minor editing mistake with the space after `.status.conditions[?`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use official `Python kubernetes-client`.

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Create new Python virtualenv:

`virtualenv -p python3 kubernetes_venv`
activate it with

`source kubernetes_venv/bin/activate`

and install kubernetes client with:

`pip install kubernetes`

Create new Python script and run:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.BatchV1Api()
ret = v1.list_namespaced_job(namespace='<YOUR-JOB-NAMESPACE>', watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print(i.status.succeeded)
```

Remember to set up your specific `kubeconfig` in `~/.kube/config` and valid value for your job namespace -> `'<YOUR-JOB-NAMESPACE>'`

Comment: Not sure this is an exhaustive answer, because there is also `job.status.failed` field.  I now observe that if the job succeeded, than the `job.status.failed` is `None`.  I wonder if `job.status.failed` is 1, could the `job.status.succeeded` be `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `-w` or `--watch`:

```
$ kubectl get jobs.batch --watch
NAME     COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
python   0/1           3m4s       3m4s
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob` and `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob` allow us to check whether the job completed but there is no way to check if the job just finished executing (irrespective of success or failure). If this is what you are looking for, a simple bash `while loop` with `kubectl status check` did the trick for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
status=$(kubectl get job jobname -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[0].type}')
echo "$status" | grep -qi 'Complete' && echo "0" && exit 0
echo "$status" | grep -qi 'Failed' && echo "1" && exit 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the best answer, from a comment by @Coo, If you add a `-f` or `--follow` option when getting logs, it'll keep tailing the log and terminate when the job **completes or fails**. The `$#` status code is even non-zero when the job fails.

```
kubectl logs -l job-name=myjob --follow
```

One downside of this approach, that I'm aware of, is that there's no timeout option.

Another downside is the logs call may fail while the pod is in `Pending` (while the containers are being started). You can fix this by waiting for the pod:

```
# Wait for pod to be available; logs will fail if the pod is "Pending"
while [[ "$(kubectl get pod -l job-name=myjob -o json | jq -rc '.items | .[].status.phase')" == 'Pending' ]]; do
    # Avoid flooding k8s with polls (seconds)
    sleep 0.25
done

# Tail logs
kubectl logs -l job-name=myjob --tail=400 -f
```

Comment: Thanks. You can send the output of `kubectl logs` to the background first with `&`, like: `kubectl logs -l job-name=myjob --follow &`. Then you can run `kubectl wait` immediately after as in @abagshaw's answer (for example in a CI script). This will stream your logs to the output while waiting for the job to finish.

Answer (score 0):

It either one of these queries with `kubectl`

```
kubectl get job test-job -o jsonpath='{.status.succeeded}'
```

or

```
kubectl get job test-job -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}'
```