# Kubernetes cronjob email alerts

Tags: cron, kubernetes

I have few cronjobs configured and running in Kubernetes. How to setup up cronjob email alerts for success or failure in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 5):

This could be as easy as setting up a bash script with `kubectl` to send an email if you see a job that is `Failed` state.

```
while true; do if `kubectl get jobs myjob -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Failed")].status}' | grep True`; then mail email@address -s jobfailed; else sleep 1 ; fi; done
```

or on newer K8s:

```
while true; do kubectl wait --for=condition=failed job/myjob; mail@address -s jobfailed; done
```

How to tell whether a Job is complete: [Kubernetes - Tell when Job is Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686568/kubernetes-tell-when-job-is-complete)

You can also setup something like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) with [Alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/) in your Kubernetes cluster to monitor your Jobs.

Some useful info [here](https://medium.com/@tristan_96324/prometheus-k8s-cronjob-alerts-94bee7b90511) and [here](https://itnext.io/kubernetes-monitoring-with-prometheus-in-15-minutes-8e54d1de2e13).