# Wait for kubernetes jobs to finish

Tags: kubernetes

Here is a list of jobs that i´m running:

```
>kubectl get jobs 
NAME                 COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
create-samplenames   1/1           32s        25h
download-db          1/1           20s        26h
download-fastq       1/1           20s        26h
download-scripts     1/1           22s        32m
trimming-fasta-1     0/1           63s        63s
trimming-fasta-2     0/1           63s        63s
trimming-fasta-3     0/1           63s        63s
trimming-fasta-4     0/1           62s        62s
```

I´m trying to wait until the trimming-fasta-* jobs are finished. I have found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862487/how-to-wait-until-kubernetes-list-of-pods-are-successful-using-shell-script) but it will return TRUE for some jobs that are finised. I really want to wait for all the trimming-fasta-* jobs are finisihed ??

```
until kubectl  get jobs   -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}' ; do sleep 1 ; done
True True True True(base) [david@archlinux otustaxonomy]$
```

Any idea to only check for trimming jobs. By the way they all belong to the same jobgrooup but havn´t found anything to check for jobgroup completion

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: trimming-fasta-$idx
  namespace: namespace-test
  labels:
    jobgroup: trimming
spec:....
```

Any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`kubectl wait`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) usage:

> $ **wait** ([-f FILENAME] | resource.group/**resource.name** | resource.group
>   [(**-l label** | --all)]) [**--for**=delete|--for **condition**=available]

You can use labels with `kubectl wait`, so just do the following to wait for all *trimming* jobs:

`kubectl wait jobs -l jobgroup=trimming --for=condition=complete`