# kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=30s

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to check the status of a pod using kubectl wait command through this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait).
Following is the command that i am trying

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=30s -n d1 job/test-job1-oo-9j9kj
```

Following is the error that i am getting

```
Kubectl error: status.conditions accessor error: Failure is of the type string, expected map[string]interface{}
```

and my `kubectl -o json` output can be accessed via this github [link](https://github.com/msraju2009/kubernetes-tests/blob/master/kubernetes-json-output.json).

Can someone help me to fix the issue

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66439

Comment: @ljaz can you please suggest me if any other approach is there to achive this.I have a list of pods which will take 1hr or less to complete. I want to know the status if pods are completed or not by that time

Comment: are you trying to check if a pod is completed or not? or trying to check if a job is completed? In case of job, that command works to me.

Comment: Yes I am trying to wait for the job to complete and job may take 1 hr or less..I found wait command useful but it is not working

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This totally looks like you are running `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete` on a [Pod](https://github.com/msraju2009/kubernetes-tests/blob/master/kubernetes-json-output.json) as described in your output rather than a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/).

A pod doesn't have the `--for=condition=complete` option. Exactly, what I get when I run it on a pod:

```
$ kubectl wait --for=condition=complete pod/mypod-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx
error: .status.conditions accessor error: Failure is of the type string, expected map[string]interface{}
```

Answer (score 67):

To wait until your pod is running, check for "condition=ready". In addition, prefer to filter by label, rather than specifying pod id. For example:

```
$ kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l app=netshoot 
pod/netshoot-58785d5fc7-xt6fg condition met
```

Another option is [rollout status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-status-em-) - To wait until the deployment is done:

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment netshoot
deployment "netshoot" successfully rolled out
```

Both options work great in automation scripts, when it is required to wait for an app to be installed. However, as @CallMeLaNN noted for the second option, deployment "rolled out" does not check if its pods are ready or failed.

**Update:**
A very handy tip I found about [kubectl wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_wait/#examples) is to use `--for jsonpath` if the available conditions are not sufficient. For example, to wait up to 3m for an Operator Subscription with an InstalPlan to be ready, I don't check for its condition but for its state:

```
$ kubectl wait --for jsonpath='{.status.state}'=AtLatestKnown sub mysub -n myns --timeout=3m
```

Comment: Any problem with `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready` above from your experience? I think it doesn't quite reliable. Sometimes it get timed out after apply/rollout restart even thought `kubectl get pods` returns ready.

Comment: I have a followup question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62726150/186334

Comment: @CallMeLaNN that's why I try to use [rollout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rollout) when possible (only for deployments, daemonsets, and statefulsets).

Comment: Currently I'm using `rollout restart` for development after replace `latest` tag and `set image` tag for production. That will recreate new pods. Then I want to wait and fail the pipeline if not ready. IMO `kubectl rollout status` only wait until rollout completed regardless if the pod ready or error.

Comment: Thanks @CallMeLaNN. I've updated answer regarding rollout status.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN I have the same problem. Some time it wait until timeout, some time it works properly. Any alternative ways?

Comment: can you suggest syntax of *wait deploy/name condition=replicas=0(all pods terminated)*?

Answer (score 6):

As outlined by Rico you can't wait for the complete state on the pod, assuming you want to wait for the job to complete use the following

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=30s -n d1 job/test-job1
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if --for=condition=complete doesn't exist, you can use --for=condition=ready=False

This will wait until your pod stop running which is what you seem to want. At least, it worked for me.