# kubectl wait sometimes timed out unexpectedly

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I just add `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l app=appname --timeout=30s` in the last step of BitBucket Pipeline to report any deployment failure if the new pod somehow producing error.

**I realize that the wait doesn't really consistent. Sometimes it gets timed out even if new pod from new image doesn't producing any error, pod turn to ready state.**

> Try to always change deployment.yaml or push newer image everytime to test this, the result is inconsistent.

BTW, I believe using `kubectl rollout status` doesn't suitable, I think because it just return after the deployment done without waiting for pod ready.

Note that there is not much difference if I change timeout from `30s` to `5m` since apply or rollout restart is quite instant.

- kubectl version: 1.17
- AWS EKS: latest 1.16

Comment: I tried `wait` with couple of deployment combinations and never experienced this. I did found out weird behavior when I downgraded kubectl to lowered version than server. Can you check this behavior with `kubectl` match with your server version?

Comment: I think the problem is my pods went ready for a moment before crash/error because that is what my NodeJs do; starting up and then throw an error due to missing env variable. I'm still testing it with real Pipeline and will post an answer if that is 100% working. Basically after deploy, I `sleep 5`s (skip running pods), `rollout status` and `rollout status` again (in case sometime the first one exited prematurely).

Comment: @acid_fuji thank you a lot! I had the issue exactly because of versions: my kubectl client was behind server

Answer (score 2):

I'm placing this answer for better visibility as noted in the comments this indeed solves some problems with `kubectl wait` behavior.

I managed to replicate the issue and have some timeouts when my client version was older than server version.  You have to match your client version with server in order to `kubectl wait` work properly.