# kubectl wait for a pod to complete

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod spec which runs a command like `rm -rf /some/path`

i create the pod using `kubectl apply -f ...`

now i want to wait till the pod completes.
i can see that the pod is done, `kubectl get pod/<mypod>` shows `STATUS Completed`

How do i wait for this condition?

i have looked at `kubectl wait ...` but  that doesnt seem to help me

`kubectl wait --for=condition=complete pod/<my-pod>` seems to just block.
I havent deleted the pod, it is still there in the Completed status

Answer (score 10):

The command that you use: `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete pod/<my-pod>` will not work because a pod doesn't have such condition. [Pod Conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions) are as follows:

- `PodScheduled`: the Pod has been scheduled to a node.
- `ContainersReady`: all containers in the Pod are ready.
- `Initialized`: all init containers have started successfully.
- `Ready`: the Pod is able to serve requests and should be added to the load balancing pools of all matching Services.

The [phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) for a successfully completed pod is called `succeeded`:

> All containers in the Pod have terminated in success, and will not be
> restarted.

It would be better however if you use `kubectl wait` for [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) instead of bare Pods and than execute `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob`.

Answer (score 0):

As supposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036091/14355362), you can use
the condition `Ready=False`. The following script waits until the pod stops running. It timeouts after 1 hour.

```bash
# wait until pod starts
kubectl wait --for condition=Ready pod/pod-name
# then wait until pod stops
kubectl wait --for condition=Ready=False --timeout=1h pod/pod-name
```