# Kubernetes Job Status check

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Quick question regarding Kubernetes job status.

Lets assume I submit my resource to 10 PODS and want to check if my JOB is completed successfully.

What is the best available options that we can use from KUBECTL commands.

I think of kubectl get jobs but the problem here is you have only two codes 0 & 1. 1 for completion 0 for failed or running, we cannot really depend on this

Other option is kubectl describe to check the PODS status like out of 10 PODS how many are commpleted/failed.

Any other effective way of monitoring the PODs? Please let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes - Tell when Job is Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686568/kubernetes-tell-when-job-is-complete)

Answer (score 1):

Anything that can talk to the Kubernetes API can query for Job object and look at the `JobStatus` field, which has info on which pods are running, completed, failed, or unavailable. `kubectl` is probably the easiest, as you mentioned, but you could write something more specialized using any client library if you wanted/needed to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to able to achieve it by running the following, which will show the status of the container:

```
kubectl describe job
```