# Python request : download when status complete

Tags: python, json, api, jobs

I have to write a script to catch some info in an API with python
It looks like this post [Tell when Job is Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686568/tell-when-job-is-complete) but without Kubernetes stuff

I have a json format like this :

```
[{'name': 'E56a, character.',
'results': '*some url link*',
'status': 'Complete',
'token': 'qFTDHYiuf514oz'}]
```

When I submit my job, the status is 'running' until it finished and became 'complete' but It last about one hour and depend on the file I want to submit to the website ...
I wanted to know how can write in my script something that will allow me to download result when the status key is completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an infinite loop that checks every 60 seconds (you can change the interval) if the job is ready:

```
import time
while True:
    if job["status"] == "Completed":
        download_results() # implement here your logic
        break
    else:
        print("Job is not ready, waiting...")
        time.sleep(60) # you can change the check interval
```