# Knowing the replica count in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm wondering for a batch distributed job I need to run. Is there a way in K8S if I use a Job/Stateful Set or whatever, a way for the pod itself(via ENV var or whatever) to know its 1 of X pods run for this job?

I need to chunk up some data and have each process fetch the stuff it needs.

--

I guess the statefulset hostname setting is one way of doing it. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is planned but not yet implemented that I know of. You probably want to look into higher order layers like Argo Workflows or Airflow instead for now.

Comment: Got pointed to Argo earlier today for something completely different. Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is good to know. Do you have a link to a feature request or other documents about this planned feature?

Comment: It's mentioned in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#parallel-jobs and still chattered about every now and then by sig-api-machinery.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some infrastructure as code using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) that will perform the following tasks in order:

1. `kubectl create -f jobs.yml`
2. `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/job1`
3. `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/job2`
4. `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/job3`
5. `kubectl create -f pod.yml`

[kubectl wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) can be used in situations like this to halt progress until an action has been performed. In this case, a job has completed its run.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686568/tell-when-job-is-complete) is a similar question that someone asked on StackOverflow before.

Comment: This would be for running jobs in sequence, not getting a stable global index between parallel steps.

Comment: Sorry, bit different to that. I need to know inside the pod what number it is out of X.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think @coderanger is right in that Argo Workflows might be the best solution for you.