# Helm pre-install job is created before service account

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

As part of my applications helm chart I have a Job which runs database migrations. I’ve annotated the job with the hook `"helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade` to ensure migrations are ran before the application is deployed. I want to use the same service account and config-map that my application deployment uses, however these resources have not been created at the time the job is executed resulting in the following error:

`Warning  FailedCreate  8s    job-controller  Error creating: pods "db-migrate-" is forbidden: error looking up service account dev-platform/platform: serviceaccount "platform" not found`

According to the helm installation [order](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090/pkg/tiller/kind_sorter.go#L29) the service account and config map should be created before the job. Is the behaviour nullified when running the job as `pre-install`?:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: dev-platform
  name: db-migrate
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 300
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    spec:
      # Share platform service account IAM role.
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Release.Name }}
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534 #  Allow read permissions of AWS token files for IAM service account token.
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: db-migrate
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: platform-config
            - secretRef:
                name: platform-secrets
          # Overwrite APP_COMMAND variable.
          env:
            - name: APP_COMMAND
              value: migrate
            - name: APP_ENVIRONMENT
              value: {{ .Values.image.appEnvironment | quote }}
```

Answer (score 10):

Helm hooks are not limited to Jobs.

You can create the serviceaccount and configmap in the pre-install phase itself using the same helm-hook annotation as the Job.

Note: If you need the serviceaccount and configmap available after the pre-install phase, do not set the 'helm.sh/hook-delete-policy' to 'hook-succeeded'.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: my-sa    
    annotations:
      helm.sh/hook: pre-install
      helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation
      helm.sh/hook-weight: "-10"
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach I ended up implementing. However could you clarify not setting the `hook-delete-policy`. Coincidentally I have `"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded` set for the confimap and secrets file required for the job and it seems to work, I just want the configmap and secrets availble for the job and once the job is complete they can be removed.

Comment: Yes if the configmap and serviceaccount are not used after the pre-install phase, you can set the delete-policy to hook-succeeded. It will be available for your job, but not afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, From the official docs, a pre-install hook:

> Executes after templates are rendered, but before any resources are created in Kubernetes
> ([docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/))

I would suggest to have the migrations as an init-container to your main app's pod. That way, reusing the existing configmaps and service accounts becomes trivial. Init-Containers need to run to completion before the pods containers are started. That way, you can also make sure that the database is migrated prior to starting your app. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) for the official documentation on init-containers.

Comment: Thanks @winston. I was straying away from this approach due to the fact that every pod being deployed runs the Init-container. Wouldn't this cause issues particularly when executing database migrations if more than one pod is being created at the same time? If I do continue down the pre-install hook route It looks like I'll have to pass the database configuration in a different approach (Maybe creating the jobs own config-map pulled from the same values file as the application)

Comment: Hey @JamesDowning! It all comes down to the app you're deploying. Ideally, the container running the migrations should lock the database while doing so, while the other replicas of the pod wait until the migrations are done. This however requires a particularly robust app which isn't always feasable. An alternative approach to init-jobs would be to also deploy a plain old Job with helm that runs the migrations and have init-jobs that check if said Migration job is already finished, somewhat like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686568/tell-when-job-is-complete

Answer (score 0):

When I'm run `ServiceAccount` creation using Helm hooks as in the previous example getting this error (confusing a little):

`Error: ServiceAccount "demo-33-service-account" is invalid: metadata.labels: Invalid value: "-10": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')`

It's because of `helm.sh/hook-weight: "-10"`.

I'm also tried to use only positive weights (0 for `ServiceAccount` and 10 for `Job`), but with no luck - `Job` started before `ServiceAccount` created and stucked. When I manually remove the stucked `Job`, `ServiceAccount` created by hook successfully. Think it is because hooks *executes after templates are rendered, but before any resources are created in Kubernetes* (see [pre-install in docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)).

Maybe `post-install` hook for `Job` will rescue, but I solved the issue using `initContainers` for my migration job (thanks @winston).